# JavaScript function to load website homepage only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a personal website. I have a homepage and several other pages -- I want to be able to get back to the homepage by clicking a "home" button, so I made a javascript function `loadhomepage()` to be executed anytime the home button is clicked. It works to load the homepage when you initially go to the site, but when I call it to load the homepage after navigating to a different page, it doesn't display the elements.

I looked at a couple similar questions on stackoverflow but those seemed to be issues with numerical calculations ([Javascript counter works only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464492/javascript-counter-works-only-once) & [JavaScript function will only work once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834034/javascript-function-will-only-work-once)), whereas mine is fading elements in and out so those don't address my problem.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martyjay60/c3tp1swj/

As you can see, the `load_homepage` function yields a blank page instead of all the elements it had in the beginning. Any help would be much appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna think about selecting the divs you want to `fadeOut` in this snippet

```
$("#home.scroll").on('click', function(event) {
   $("div:visible").fadeOut(500);
   load_homepage();
 });
```

This is causing the `.homepage` to be `display:none` and you're never fading it back in in your `load_homepage()` function.

I added this to your code and the content comes back:

```
function load_homepage() {
   $.when($(".homepage").fadeIn(1000), $("#namebox").fadeIn(1000))
   ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6sc2wjye/

Comment: i used "div:visible" because the home button is only available to be clicked when you're away from the homepage -- at which time the homepage is not visible (```display: none```). your solution doesn't quite work because the ```load_homepage()``` function is to fade in different elements of the homepage at different speeds, not the entire homepage at once.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to fade in your .homepage div, change the on click event listener to:

```js
    $("#home.scroll").on('click', function(event) {
        $("div:visible").fadeOut(500);
        $.when($(".homepage").fadeIn(700))
        .done(load_homepage);
    });
```

This will solve the problem.

Comment: the function ```load_homepage``` is supposed to fade in all the elements of the .homepage div at various speeds; if i fade in the homepage all at once, the ```load_hompage``` function has nothing left to accomplish

Comment: Then, you need to set the div inside `.homepage` (#resume, #projects, #about, #contact, #name) with the same fade out operation, when fade out `.homepage`. You can create an `unload_homepage` function to group those fade out operation.

Comment: when i click on a tab away from the homescreen, i have ```$.when($(".homepage").fadeOut(700))```
thus, the homepage elements aren't visible elements and i should be able to fade them in with load_homepage, no?

Comment: Press `F12` in chrome, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`c` to select the element you want to inspect. Watch the value inside style changing in different stage. You will understand better.
Basically, fadeIn animate the object opacity to 1, meanwhile, fadeOut animate the object opacity to 0 then change display to none.
`$.when($(".homepage").fadeOut(700))` only fadeOut `.homepage`, but `div` inside `.homepage` is still have opacity = 1, so fadeIn them won't give you any animation effect, since they are change opacity from 1 to 1 rather 0 to 1